# Splitting field justification

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (where $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the real $\sqrt[3]{2}$) a root field over $\mathbb Q$? Additionally, is $\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{3})$ a root field over $\mathbb Q$?

I don't think $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a root field because the polynomial $x^3-$, where $\sqrt[3]{2})$ comes from has complex roots that will not be in the extension.

And $i+\sqrt{3}$ comes from the polynomial $x^4 - 4 x^2 + 16$ which I believe also has complex roots but I think they are included. So I think it may be a root field.

Am I on the right track

Comment: Is.... **what** ? Check your first sentence's logic and redaction.

Comment: A root field is what my book calls a splitting field, or so I believe

Comment: @K Math I understand that...yet I still can't understand your very first sentence.

Comment: I added some punctuation to help. If I'm honest I'm not even sure what the real $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}$) means?

Comment: Oh, I see !! Now that changes all (puntuation is so important...) . Thanks. "the real" seems to mean "the real root of $\;x^3-2\;$, though that's not implicitly written

Answer (score 2):

Now, $\;\Bbb Q(\alpha)\;$ is **always** a field whenever $\;\alpha\;$ is a root in, say $\;\Bbb C\;$ ( or any other algebraically closed field containing $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ) of some non-zero rational polynomial.

In our case, the minimal (and thus irreducible) polynomial of $\;\sqrt[3]2\;$ is $\;x^3-2\;$ . If $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2\;)\;$ were a splitting field over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , then it'd contain **all** the roots of *any* irreducible rational polynomial having one root in it. Yet, the given field is **real**, meaning $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\subset\Bbb R\;$ , whereas the other two (non-real) roots of $\;x^3-2\;$ are complex non-real: $\;\sqrt[3]2\,\omega\,,\,\,\sqrt[3]2\,\omega^2\;$ , with $\;\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}=\;$ a (primitive) root of unity of order three.

Thus, $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\;$ is a field but **not** a splitting field over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ as it doesn't contain **all** the roots of the irreducible $\;x^3-2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , but containing one of them.

Answer (score 1):

For the second field $F=\mathbf Q(i+\sqrt 3)$, the minimal polynomial of the generator is $x^4-4x^2+16$. Its roots  are 
$$ \bigl\{i+\sqrt 3,\, -i-\sqrt 3,\, i-\sqrt 3,\,-i+\sqrt 3 \bigr\}.$$
Let's set $\omega=i+\sqrt 3$. The second root lies in $F$, and the third (and therefore the fourth) root too. 
Indeed  try to write
$$i-\sqrt 3=x+y\,\omega+z\,\omega^2+t\,\omega^3=x+y(i+\sqrt 3)+2z(1-i\sqrt3)+8ti. $$
This leads to the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
x+\sqrt 3\,y+2z=-\sqrt3 ,\\
y-2z\sqrt3+8t=1,
\end{cases}\qquad(x,y,z,t\in\mathbf Q).$$
Since $\sqrt 3$ is irrational, we deduce
$$\begin{cases}
x+2z=0,& y=-1 ,\\
y+8t=1,& z=0.
\end{cases}\quad\text{whence}\quad x=z=0,\;y=-1,\;t=\frac14.$$
As a conclusion, $\mathbf Q(i+\sqrt 3)$ is the splitting field of $x^4-4x^2+16$.

Comment: Just curious how you conclude that since $i+\sqrt{3}$ is in $F$ then so are the second and third roots

Comment: The second root is the opposite of the first. AS to the third, I solved the above equations., which shows the third root is a polynomial in the first root.

Comment: ok thank you! May I ask you about $\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$? I realize I'm not supposed to ask more than one question on each post but I am looking to do the same thing and can't figure out the minimal polynomial. Can I assume $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: If you can show this element has a minimal polynomial of degree $8$, yes. *A priori*, one of the proofs of the primitive element theorem shows this field can be generated by $i+\lambda \sqrt 2+\mu \sqrt 3$ for some $\lambda, \mu\in\mathbf Q$. Finding $\lambda$ and $\mu$ can require quite some calculations.

Comment: @Bernard, it’s certainly true that it requires work to show that any particular $i+\lambda\sqrt2+\mu\sqrt3$ is a primitive element. But roughly speaking, almost any choice of $(\lambda,\mu)$ will give you such an element.